# Remove Location Manager alert from my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I used Location Manager API for find out Latitude and Longitude of the current place.
But when i called update location manager method i get some alert from application which i have attach along this message.
I want to remove this alert message and by default i want to set YES or (Allow) for that.
Is it possible or not?

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to do that. It is done to safeguard user's security. If you've been following the PATH ADDRESSBOOK issues, it was raised 'coz Path App didn't ask users before using their Address Book. So Apple's implemented the *asking feature* or permission by default in Core Location and Push Notifications. And By the looks of it, in the address book as well and you will have to stick to it - After all, you don't want to fall into privacy issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible,This dialog would be shown once when the app starts

Answer (score 1):

You cannot and even if you could, probably your App wouldn't be accepted by Apple.